# shopware 6 2 product slider in mobile

Tags: css, product, shopware6

i am trying to place 2 products side by side in mobile view. I tried to edit the css and i could only get 1 product inside the slider.

can anyone help me here?

Thanks
Prashanth[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZZw2.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution: You can set the min-width to a lower value. By this the products will use less space (on desktop and mobile) and more products will be shown.

[image: Setting min width]

Shopware internally uses [tiny-slider](https://github.com/ganlanyuan/tiny-slider) for this element. Only some of it's options are configurable in the CMS and set in `vendor/shopware/storefront/Resources/views/storefront/element/cms-element-product-slider.html.twig`.

The [`responsive`-option](https://github.com/ganlanyuan/tiny-slider#responsive-options) can give you more control over the appearance of the slider in different screen sizes.

You can for example override the mentioned template to set custom options (or create a own CMS element which lets you configure all those options).

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your input. I am relatively new to shopware. I have somehow followed the tiny-slider document and did the html, css and js. The question is how to implement these in shopware core?

Comment: You can create own extension and overwrite the templates from the core.